# If (var !="String") is always true

Tags: c#

When I ask from user and input, it always falls in the loop even if it is the right input or not:

```
Console.WriteLine("Μήπως σκέφτηκες το " + n);
answr = Console.ReadLine();
while (answr != "N" || answr != "Y")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Δεν μπορώ να καταλάβω την απάτηση σου. Ξαναπροσπάθησε: ");
    answr = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: answr != "N" || answr != "Y" should be answr != "N" && answr != "Y"

Comment: Because the answer is always not equal `"N"` OR not equal `"Y"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong `(answr != "N" || answr != "Y")`

It should be `(answr != "N" && answr != "Y")`

If `answr == "N"` then it won't equal "Y", returning true.
If `answr == "Y"` then it won't equal "N", also returning true.

Comment: Thanks you. Never thought about it!